# element "button" not allowed as child of element "form"

Tags: html, forms, button, netbeans

Netbeans tells me the following Error:

```
element "button" not allowed as child of element "form"
```

Here is my code:

```
<form action="traeger.php" method="post"><button name="traeger" type="submit" value="1" class="button">XYZ</button></form>
```

All works well, but the error codes razz me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">` instead of `<button type="submit">XYZ</button>`

Comment: it is possible. but what is wrong with my code?

and with a button i can adjust many beautiful things in CSS

Comment: There's no reason why you can't use button (except IE6 and IE7 compatibility issues). But if you want to get rid of the error, you can still style the input field with css. Just give it a class like you did with your button: `<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">`

Answer (score 0):

[This is what the specification says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-button-element). It is totally fine to use a `<button>` element inside of a `<form>` element. I guess Netbeans doesn’t reflect the HTML5 specification here but a prior one (not sure if in HTML4 this wasn’t allowed but I suspect so).

This given there’s no need to alter your markup or switching to an input if you don’t need or want to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Netbeans applies syntax checks that follow HTML 4.01 Strict rules, according to which a `form` element must not contain any text-level (inline) children, i.e. all text-level descendants must be wrapped in block-level containers. This is purely formal (and questionable) and does not affect functionality the least. But to silence the message, use a `div` wrapper:

```
<form action="traeger.php" method="post">div><button name="traeger" type="submit"
value="1" class="button">XYZ</button></div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your DTD in the HTML file? If it is for HTML 4.01 you cannot blame NetBeans for this valid "error". Having `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it works just fine for me